# Django Serializer not showing related fields

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I can't get the State field to appear in the result. Don't know why.

My model:

```
class City(models.Model):
   city_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   state = models.ForeignKey('State', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

   class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'city'

   def __str__(self):
       return self.city

class State(models.Model):
   state_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   state = models.CharField(max_length = 10, blank=True, null=True)

   class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'state'
```

My serializer:

```
class StateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ('state_id', 'state')


class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     state = StateSerializer(source='state_set', many=False, read_only = True)
   class Meta:
       model = City
       fields = ('city_id', 'city', 'state')
```

My Views:

```
class CityList(APIView):
    # Return all the cities
   def get(self, request):
       cities = City.objects.all()
       serializer = CitySerializer(cities, many=True)
       return Response(serializer.data)

   def post(self):
       pass
```

My result JSON:

```
[
{
    "city_id": 242,
    "city": null
},
{
    "city_id": 754,
    "city": "CARY"
},
{
    "city_id": 2085,
    "city": "FROM YOUR"
},...
```

How can I get the state field to appear in the JSON result? Can someone help? I got several tables like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have bad relation in **CitySerializer**.

**City** dont have **state_set** relation... it have only one **state**.

**CitySerializer** should look like this:

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Removed source.. by default it's like the field name
    # I removed also many=False because it's default

    state = StateSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('city_id', 'city', 'state')
```